# Flutter rest GETX map inside Obx not refreshing data on gui side

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-getx

Hello I have simple script I download data from from Rest api , there is my controller
and when I submit the button I Clear the list inside object Employee, after click I call the deleteEmployee() (int the future CRUD operations per row inside table,) , data are cleared, but data inside widget they are not refreshed. and I would like somethin more with that I need to show in table and make same operation per row.

I cant figure where is a problem.

[image]

after click the button must look like

[image]

```
class EmployeeController extends GetxController {

  var empData = <Employe>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchEmployee();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchEmployee() async {
    final response =
    await http.get(
        Uri.parse('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final string = response.body;
      final parsed = json.decode(string);
      Employe emp = Employe.fromJson(parsed);

     Employe empx = Employe(  message: "sampleTest", status: '123', data: emp.data.getRange(0, 4).toList() );

      List<Employe> e = [];
      e.add(empx);
      e.add(emp);
      
      empData.value = e;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load emplo');
    }
  }

  void deleteEmployee (String enumId){

    debugPrint(empData.toString());
    debugPrint("before");
    int index = empData.indexWhere((ele) => ele.message == enumId);
    empData[index].data.clear();
    debugPrint("after");
    debugPrint(empData.toString());
  }


}
```

```
void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

final EmployeeController employeeController = Get.put(EmployeeController());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 // This widget is the root of your application.
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
   );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

 final String title;

 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Obx(() => Row(
         children: employeeController.empData
             .map(
               (e) => Expanded(
                 child: Column(
                   children: [
                     Text(e.message),
                     Text(e.toString()),
                     IconButton(
                       onPressed: () {
                         employeeController.deleteEmployee(e.message);
                       },
                       icon: Icon(Icons.abc_rounded),
                     )
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             )
             .toList())),
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In *_MyHomePageState* try to use `employeeController.empData.value` instead of `employeeController.empData`.

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Obx(() => Row(
         children: employeeController.empData.value
             .map(
               (e) => Expanded(
                 child: Column(
                   children: [
                     Text(e.message),
                     Text(e.toString()),
                     IconButton(
                       onPressed: () {
                         employeeController.deleteEmployee(e.message);
                       },
                       icon: Icon(Icons.abc_rounded),
                     )
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             )
             .toList())),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, as it is automatically converted to a RxList, which does not need to be accessed with `.value`

Comment: I try, but nothing, not work